# How to center in available space, but not use infinite height in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Pre-conditions:

- We can use a `LayoutBuilder` to obtain the height available for `ListView`
- We don't know the height of Widget A or Widget B.

How can Widget B be centered in the available space in the left situation while still not causing Flutter to use infinite height for the space to center Widget B within?

[image]

Some basic code for the situation:

```dart
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
  return ListView(
    children: [
      Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            WidgetA(),
            WidgetB(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]
  );
}),
```

I would like to wrap WidgetB in Expanded but only up to the total height of `constraints.maxHeight` for WidgetA + WidgetB to not get the infinite height exception.

```dart
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
  return ListView(
    children: [
      Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            WidgetA(),
            Expanded(WidgetB()), // Infinite height exception
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]
  );
}),
```

Answer (score 2):

The probably easiest solution is to use slivers with `CustomScrollView`. There is a sliver class [`SliverFillRemaining`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverFillRemaining-class.html) which is a perfect match to the problem in this question.

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: WidgetA(),
    ),
    SliverFillRemaining(
      hasScrollBody: false,
      child: Center(
        child: WidgetB(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/PixelToast/94dc9d5f3f16a933e18ae84dbaa8c3af) ([dart pad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=94dc9d5f3f16a933e18ae84dbaa8c3af)) I got suggested on FlutterDev Discord.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```html
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
  return ListView(
    children: [
      Column(
        children: [
          //WidgetA
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: WidgetA(),
          ),
          //WidgetB
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: WidgetB(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ]
  );
}),
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I don't want to set the heights in the layout. In my app widgetA() is complex and has different heights depending on its internal state not known to the layout problem in this question. Sorry if this was not clear enough in the question. I tried to disclosure it as a precondition in the beginning.